# How to get Entity Name in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have first project that dealing with coreData. I followed [this tutorial](http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/downloads/SignificantDates-Final.zip). Everything was fine until I created new project with new core data models that has same fields and same structure to have deeper understand. However, I couldn't figure out where the variable  self.entityName in class SDDateTableViewController.m got assigned value. Because the variable self.entityName in my new project is getting nil in method -(void)loadRecordsFromCoreData in SDDateTableViewController.m class.

Note: I did try copy every single line of code to my project, but the variable self.entityName is still nil

Please help me explain this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is define in the Storyboard on the SDDateTableViewController scene on "User defined runtime attributes".

[image]